# Surah Yusuf (12), Ayaah 23

Tags: quran, quran-recitation, qiraat, surat-yusuf

I was wondering why do Qaris get the independence of adding extra texts to [12:23](https://quran.com/12/23) of the noble Quran? I am adding a link to Qari Abdul Basit's recitation. 
https://youtu.be/kBII2vQ4aNU?t=127 Timestamp [2:07]

Comment: And what is this extra text?

Comment: @Medi1Saif  The repeating part is this قَالَتْ هَيْتَ لَكَ

Comment: @UmH I'm afraid that I'm not convinced. Because that part was being recited differently maybe four times. Firstly, I noticed the issue from Hady Toure's recitation which checked and thought there might be another ayaah which I don't know of. But now I'm sure that it's 12:23. 
Still waiting on a proper explanation. Check out Hady Toure's recitation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pp6Z0-WkC4k

Comment: Thanks for the tips @UmH and I seek excuse for I'm new on this platform. Hady Toure's timestamp is [9:26] and I have added Basit's in the question. 

Could you be explaining why wouldn't repeating a/two word(s) differently be adding extra text?

Answer (score 1):

In your given video from [1:15 to 1:43](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kBII2vQ4aNU&feature=youtu.be&t=75) and [2:04 to 2:20](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kBII2vQ4aNU&feature=youtu.be&t=124), the Qari Abdul Basit repeats part of the ayah of [Surah Yusuf](https://quran.com/12/23) in different recitations:

- The recitation of Nafi', Abu Jafar and Shaybah:

  [image]

  > وقرأ أبو جعفر وشيبة ونافع" وَقَالَتْ هِيتَ لَكَ" بكسر الهاء وفتح التاء
  >
  > <sup>— [Tafsir al-Qurtubi](https://archive.org/stream/waq73651/11_73661#page/n306/mode/2up)</sup>
  >
  > وقرأ أهل المدينة والشام: «هِيتَ» بكسر الهاء وفتح التاء
  >
  > <sup>— [Tafsir al-Baghawy](https://archive.org/stream/malimtmalimt8/malimt4#page/n226/mode/2up)</sup>
- The recitation of Ibn Kathir:

  [image]

  > وقرأ أبو عبد الرحمن السلمي وابن كثير" هَيْتُ لَكَ" بفتح الهاء وضم التاء
  >
  > <sup>— [Tafsir al-Qurtubi](https://archive.org/stream/waq73651/11_73661#page/n306/mode/2up)</sup>
  >
  > وقرأ ابن كثير: «هَيْتُ» بفتح الهاء وضم التاء
  >
  > <sup>— [Tafsir al-Baghawy](https://archive.org/stream/malimtmalimt8/malimt4#page/n226/mode/2up)</sup>
- The recitation of 'Asim, Abu 'Amr, Hamzah and Kisa'i

  [image]

  > وهذه القراءة بفتح التاء والهاء هي الصحيحة من قراءة ابن عباس وسعيد بن جبير والحسن ومجاهد وعكرمة، وبها قرأ أبو عمرو بن العلاء وعاصم والأعمش وحمزة والكسائي
  >
  > <sup>— [Tafsir al-Qurtubi](https://archive.org/stream/waq73651/11_73661#page/n306/mode/2up)</sup>
  >
  > قرأ أهل الكوفة والبصرة: هَيْتَ لَكَ بفتح الهاء والتاء جميعا
  >
  > <sup>— [Tafsir al-Baghawy](https://archive.org/stream/malimtmalimt8/malimt4#page/n226/mode/2up)</sup>
- The recitation of Ibn 'Amir:

  [image]

  > وعن ابن عامر وأهل الشام:" وَقَالَتْ هِئْتَ" بكسر الهاء وبالهمزة وبفتح التاء
  >
  > <sup>— [Tafsir al-Qurtubi](https://archive.org/stream/waq73651/11_73661#page/n306/mode/2up)</sup>

These are valid recitations, they go back to a Sahabi, to the Prophet Muhammad ﷺ, to Gabriel (عليه السلام). They are not "extra texts" which have been "added" by Abdul Basit on his own.

Refer to [What are the readings (qira'at) of Quran?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2676/what-are-the-readings-qiraat-of-quran) etc.

Comment: I'd like to point at the fact that doing this during a prayer would be considered as makruh as one should stuck to one riwaya.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Although he isn't doing so during prayer. Seems like a recitation front of an audience.

Comment: I never doubted that there would be such a recitation during a prayer. I just wanted to point at this special case.

Comment: I understand it's a minute difference, but are you saying there are slight variations in different versions of Quran?

Comment: Yes there are slight differences in the various Qira'at of the Quran, which have their origin in the seven Ahruf in which the Quran was revealed.